Freeze panes and Scrollrow in same Sheet on both screens not working in a multiscreen setup
In a multiscreen setup (6 screens) I use two screens showing different excel worksheets from same workbook. Screen A shows Sheet1 and Screen B shows Sheet2.
While working on Screen A in Sheet1 I have a Worksheet_SelectionChange VBA macro for Sheet1 manipulating the data content in Sheet2 using Autofilter.
This works fine and the auto filtered data is present as expected in both the ’hidden’ (not shown) Sheet2 on Screen A and visable Sheet2 on Screen B.
In the Sheet1 macro I’m also scrolling the Sheet2 rows to row 1 and also Freezing the panes to the top row in Sheet2.
This works for the ’hidden’ (not shown) Sheet2 on Screen A and can be seen when switching to Sheet2 on Screen A.
But scrolling to row 1 and freezing the panes does not happen in the visable Sheet2 on Screen B.
What can I do to make that happen also on Screen B?
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Intersection
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3)
    Set Intersection = Application.Intersect(Target, Rng)
           
    If Not Intersection Is Nothing Then
        
        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate: ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        Call FreezePanes(Sheets("Sheet2"), 1)
        
        Sheets("Sheet2").AutoFilterMode = False
        Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range( _
                  Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp), _
                  Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 2))
                  
        Rng.AutoFilter _
            Field:=1, _
            Criteria1:=Format(Cells(Target.row, 2).Value, "000"), _
            VisibleDropDown:=False
                    
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Target.row, 2).Select
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub FreezePanes(sht As Worksheet, row As Long)
    
    sht.Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
        .SplitRow = row
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With
    
End Sub



Well, the answer to this question was that when freezing panes in a multi windows excel application (typical in a multi screen setup) one have to loop through all windows and freeze the panes for each window.
I managed to achieve that with the following code:
Sub FreezePanes(sht As Worksheet, Optional row As Long = 1)

Dim i As Integer
Dim owc As String
Dim osh As Worksheet

owc = Application.ActiveWindow.Caption
Set osh = Application.ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet

For i = 1 To Windows.Count
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(i).Activate
    sht.Select 'Activate
    
    With ActiveWindow
        .ScrollRow = 1
        If .FreezePanes Then .FreezePanes = False
        .SplitRow = row
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With
Next i

ThisWorkbook.Windows(owc).Activate
osh.Activate

End Sub
